# Multiple DialogFragments with different functionalities

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-dialogfragment

So i'm developing Android app where user is often asked what he wants to do on some actions (Button click etc.). For that i was using `AlertDialog` and wrote text on it and added Buttons i needed. It was working super until i realized, that on device rotation, an opened AlertDialog would `disappear`.
I found on the web that the proper way to handle rotation is to use Fragment, so i choose to make class extending `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public interface YesNoListener {
    void onYes();
    void onNo();
    void onNeu();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] data = getArguments().getStringArray("data"); //vzame vrednosti, ki smo jih nastavili preden se pokliče .show();
    if(data != null) {
        switch (data.length) {
            case 3:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(data[0])
                        .setMessage(data[1])
                        .setNeutralButton(data[2], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onNeu();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
            case 4:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(data[0])
                        .setMessage(data[1])
                        .setPositiveButton(data[2], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onYes();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(data[3], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onNo();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
            case 5:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(data[0])
                        .setMessage(data[1])
                        .setPositiveButton(data[2], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onYes();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(data[3], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onNo();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNeutralButton(data[4], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ((YesNoListener) getActivity()).onNeu();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    else
        return null;
}
}
```

I used `interface` too so i could implement `Button.onClick()` behaviour in the class where i would use MyDialogFragment. With `getArguments()` i passed all texts that would be used in Dialog.

The problem is that i can only use this class for `one` Dialog, since i have to Override interface functions, but i have `multiple` Dialogs with different behaviour.

I wanted to solve this issue with three public Objects `Runnable`, where i would just initialize Runnable where i need to change the behaviour of the `Button.onClick()`

```
...
Runnable runnablePositive, runnableNegative, runnableNeutral;
...

@Override
public void onYes(){
    threadPositive.start();
}

@Override
public void onNo(){
    threadNegative.start();
}

@Override
public void onNeu(){
    threadNeutral.start();
}

static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String[] arg) {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray("data", arg);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

...and on usage:

```
threadPositive = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
         //do A
    }
};
threadNegative = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
         //do B
    }
};
threadNeutral = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
         //do C
    }
};
newInstance(new String[]{title, besedilo, nevtralno}).show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

It is working good untill i open Dialog and `rotate` (**this is the main problem**, other things somehow work) the device (reason why i use DialogFragment in the first place). All the variables are "deleted" on the rotation and i already passed all variables i needed for further work, but there comes new issue, which i have no idea how to solve: i can't pass `Objects` on rotation, whether i try with `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` or `onSaveInstanceState()` all in vain...

So i have no idea how to solve this, i had gone through hundreds of question regarding similar issue, but had no luck... And i would be grateful for any helpful advice or answer regarding this problem (even if it is a different way to solve the problem).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple dialogs with different behavior, then you should simply create more instances of your dialog and assign them different tags. Instead of doing just

```
newDialogFragment(someArgs).show(getFragmentManager(), "tag")
```

you can do

```
newDialogFragment(someArgs).show(getFragmentManager(), "dialogWithArgs")
newDialogFragment(someOtherArgs).show(getFragmentManager(), "dialogWithOtherArgs")
```

and so on. Your interface should be changed to

```
public interface YesNoListener {
    void onYes(String tag);
    void onNo(String tag);
    void onNeu(String tag);
}
```

When you call its methods from the dialog, pass the fragment tag so you know which dialog called the method. That way you can handle any number of dialogs easily.

As to saving the objects, those that don't change, go into the arguments, those that do, should be made Parcelable and saved to Bundle, if you can't, then you can create a separate fragment and call setRetainInstance(true) on it, then store the objects in it.

Comment: Seems a nice solution to get rid of Runnable, but i can't really use this since i use/build/show Dialog depending on other functions and if else statements etc. + variables defined in that functions...
Regardless, do you have any clue about the problem described at the end (on device rotate), since it would all be ok if i manage to pass Object on rotation or something?

Comment: @varuhan You need to pass all those variables as arguments to the dialog. Create several classes extending `DialogFragment` if necessary. As to saving the objects, those that don't change, go into the arguments, those that do, should be made `Parcelable` and saved to `Bundle`, if you can't, then you can create a separate fragment and call `setRetainInstance(true)` on it, then store the objects in it.

Comment: I thought about creating several classes but it seemed to me a bad solution, thus it would be a lot of similar classes... Thanks for advices

Comment: @varuhan I've edited the information into the answer.